# iOS background process similar to Android AlarmManager

Tags: ios, background, task

I've to schedule a fixed task that check some info from internet at fixed interval timer.

Into Android, I use AlarmManager with setRepeating, but I'm newbie to iOS.
There are some similar api that help me? I need a task that survive when app is killed by operating system.

Do you know a tutorial about it?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK in iOS you cannot implement such service that will stay alive after its host app is killed, also only several types of applications can run some background tasks - see documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20). You can do your task on server side and send push notification when you need users attention - if only user will allow your app to receive push notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Check link on [Apple's Multitasking Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) that add's the voip tag to `UIBackgroundModes` in Info.plist and use [setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout%3ahandler%3a) method of UIApplication to relaunch it if needed once the app is going to sleep.

Note : For this you need to take special permissions from Apple and mostly Apple rejects such app.

Another solution :-

You can store last sync date and if sync date has crossed your interval when application comes from background, you can start sync your data.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: Hi, for my purpose the "void" key causes the reject of my app by Apple. About second solution, how can I check when my sync date has crossed my interval? When app comes into background, the OS block it after 10 minutes...

Comment: Yes as I said VoIP requires special permissions from Apple. When application enters into background save that time in nsuserdefaults and when your app comes from check nsuserdefaults date with current date and if there is big difference between time, sync data and show some alert view to understand user to wait.

Comment: It's a solution, but if I need a scheduled task (for example, each 30 minutes) can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

You need local notifications of iOS

Answer (score 0):

I found that UILocalNotification was the best option for this. Unfortunately you cant trigger the app to open but you can get a notification to show up at a set interval.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILocalNotification

Answer (score 0):

You may use **[NSBackgroundActivityScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbackgroundactivityscheduler)** to pull something periodically.