# Way to update application every 24 hours

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications

I want to wake up my application every 24 hours and update something. Is there a way to do it without using silent push notification, location service and voip. For example the app "My data summary" gives the data usage on daily basis and it does not involve push notification service since i was not asked that permission. So how can i achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set an alarm every 24 hours to start the sync process?

Comment: @DanielBo I want to do it in background. If i use Alarm the notification will pop up.

Comment: did this on android, thought it might be possible on iOS as well, but => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337275/ios-background-process-similar-to-android-alarmmanager

Comment: @DanielBo for me to use background services like voip my application should be a voip application which is not. So not possible. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the silent push, location services and VoIP, all you have left is **Background Audio** or **Background fetch**.

- With background audio, you could play a silent sound to keep your application running, but the downside is that it might be killed when another application plays the sound.
- With background fetch, you cannot reliably start the application, the OS decides when it will fire up the app to fetch data. How ofter it happens depends on how much is user using your application.

*There are no other "legal" ways to achieve this kind of functionality on iOS. There are also a lot of resources available online on this topic.*

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios
- [iOS Background Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777389/ios-background-mode)

And many more, you need to research **background modes** more.